# Add a delimiter to end of each line of csv file MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix, save

I am appending to a csv file. The current code outputs a line: a;b;c;d
I need it to output a;b;c;d;
notice the extra ';' at the end of d. That is essential

```
 matrix = [a,b,c,d]
 dlmwrite('matrix.csv', matrix, 'delimiter',';','-append','roffset',0, 'precision',14)
```

any help would be appreciated.
I have had to keep variables a,b,c and d as numbers, or it makes it a character vector (or something) which makes my csv look funny

Comment: 1.- why do you need the csv to look "nice"? you are just storing data.
2.-why do you need that final `;`? If you then add more rows, you will very likely break the reading code.

Comment: It runs into a another piece of software that reads every row as an array. And that software crashes if the end of every row doesn't have a ';'

Comment: My suggetion: use `fprintf`, with the right formating

Answer (score 1):

I've always had problems with the MatLab inbuild CSV writing methods. Why don't you code your own .CSV writing method?

Here, you could make a function something like:

```
function write_to_csv(filepath, matrix)
  csv = fopen(filepath, 'a+'); % check what sort of open you'd like : https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#inputarg_permission
  for ii = 1 : numel(matrix)   % this loop depends on the dimensions of your matrix
    fprintf(csv, '%s;', matrix(ii)); % check fprintf return type, depending on the data in the matrix : https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html?searchHighlight=fprintf&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#inputarg_formatSpec
  end 
  fclose(csv);
end
```

This works for a 1D matrix you've supplied, run with:

```
write_to_csv('matrix.csv',matrix)
```

Comment: Hey man, great answer! Thank you!
Could you please check out this question for me?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981820/matlab-fprintf-precision-not-working