# Matlab fprintf correct format specifier for rounding to 14 decimal places

Tags: arrays, matlab, csv, for-loop, printf

I am using the code presented below to read a matrix and apply a semicolon (`;`) and newline at the end of every value.

I am having problems with the precision format specifier. Below the code block is a line from the csv output. You can see that columns 5 and 6 are formatted properly, but there are exponential values that I need rounded to 14 decimal places. Why isn't the '%f.14'on line 4 doing this? I thought it didn't use exponential notation?

```
function write_to_csv(filepath, decision)
    csv = fopen('matrix.csv', 'a+');
    for ii = 1:length(decision)
        format = '%d; %f.14';
        fprintf(csv, format, decision(ii));
    end 
    fprintf(csv,'\n')
    fclose(csv);
end
```

1; 1.032204e-03; -2.580511e-04; 1; 32190201170708; 17682101210450; 2; 7.600000e-01; -1;

Credit to MChandler for supplying the above code from question: [Add a delimiter to end of each line of csv file MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978945/add-a-delimiter-to-end-of-each-line-of-csv-file-matlab)

Comment: Replace `%f.14` with `%.14f`. For more information read the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#input_argument_formatSpec).

Comment: To clarify, you want `-2.580511e-04` to render instead as `-0.00025805110000`?

Comment: Yes I do toshiomagic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the format of the variable `decision`. Since you have `%d` before the `%f.14` it will render a 1-dimensional matrix as only `%d`. It will completely ignore the fixed point format specifier. If your matrix decision is indeed 1-dimensional, use `format = '%.14f';` as mentioned in the comments:

```
function write_to_csv(filepath, decision)
    csv = fopen('matrix.csv', 'a+');
    for ii = 1:length(decision)
        format = '%.14f';
        fprintf(csv, format, decision(ii));
    end 
    fprintf(csv,'\n')
    fclose(csv);
end
```

You can read up on format specifiers here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0z60p-1